# Check if table has specific row value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables called game and `gameprogress`. `Gameprogress` has a column called `state` that describes progress. Game is related to `gameprogress` trough an id.

Possible states is: 1,3,4 in gameprogress.

I want to find games without a `state = 1` and without a state = 4.  I've tried something like this:

```
select top 10 gp.gameid, count(gp.state) as dup
from gameprogress gp 
join game g on g.id= gp.gameid
where g.gamestate != 2 and gp.state != 1
group by gp.gameid
having count(gp.state)>1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CASE EXPRESSION` in the `HAVING` clause :

```
SELECT TOP 10 g.gameid
FROM game g
LEFT JOIN gameprogress gp 
 ON g.id= gp.gameid
GROUP BY g.gameid
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN gp.state = 3 THEN 1 END) = COUNT(*)
```

Comment: Looks like the right way to go. But i have an issue in not getting the games with state = 4, i've tried to:SELECT g.id
FROM game g
LEFT JOIN gameprogress gp ON g.id= gp.gameid
where g.gamestate != 2 and gp.state != 4
GROUP BY g.id
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN gp.state = 1 THEN 1 END) = 0

Comment: Why should it return games with state = 4? Should I guess the data? Edit the question and provide the data sample!

Comment: My fault. Edited the question.

Comment: @farnholdt So you want only those who has `state = 4` or `state = 2` ? Explain why so I'll know which filters to add

Comment: I only want those games which only has state = 3 and therefor not has any other states.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks.